# Why does Windows 10 local upload to NAS slows and goes back to normal with a mouse movement?

Tags: windows-10, networking, nas, samba

I have a NAS server, D-Link DNS-323, it was out of sync, saved all the data, reset the device back to RAID-1, and started copy back the files with a Windows 10 with the Samba protocol on the NAS. The total amount was around 1.5TB. I've divided the data into the part by directories. All worked perfectly with a gigabit router and on average 15MB/s ( that is almost max since the DNS-323 cpu cannot handle more). During the last directory copy (around 250GB), there was a strange action by the Windows. The copy speed dropped below to 5MB/s after some time. This can be seen from the below screen capture of the windows copy screen ( It did form the beginning I was on the investigation...)

[image: The low speed]

I've wondered the reason, the screen goes black - no!, power saving etc. - no!. First of all, the laptop was plugged in all the time.  I've prevented sleep and screen turn of form the current power plans. Nothing worked, except the mouse movement. When I see that the connection drop, I just move the touchpad a little and it goes up to around 15MB/s.
[image: The high speed]

The files are mostly large and the data reading was not a problem.

- Why does Windows 10 start to behave like this? Or it was already like this that I did not notice.
- What should I do to prevent Windows 10 to lower the copy speed?

Comment: @Romen If I keep the windows active with the trackpad all was working fine around the 15MB/s. Therefore the problem must be somewhere on the Windows side.

Comment: During the time the transfer speeds slowed, were you transferring large files, or smaller files?  You should edit your question to include that vital information from your last comment.

Comment: @Romen Are you saying that the background service was trying to run 10 hours ( the slowness extended the time from 5.5 hour to 10)? This is a Windows 10 Home with an SSD, not a server. As I said this copy was a problem

Comment: @Ramhound . Mostly large files in total around 700 files.

Comment: One of the only ways I can think of to explain that performance drop is that the Windows idle state is turned off when you move the mouse. Some part of Windows, a process, or a service on the computer may be designed to [run only when the user is not at the computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iidletrigger). It does not have to be something that was running the whole time, it may be a scheduled task that started at any point during the copy. Or it may be a service that is inactive until an event or signal triggers it to do some processing.

Comment: @Romen I see your points, however, that PC is used for some for other actions. During the copy no user action, all programs were closed, except the background. What triggered me is that this was related to only this copy. I can expect some drops but not al the time.